# how to validate 0 or empty?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form in php and javascript,
User already enter the form and change his mind,
so if it's 0 or ticked but 0 or not ticked, the form will not pass value from that textbox
[image]

Any idea how to do it ?

```
<?php
     echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]"  value="'.$amount_due.'" id="amount_checkbox_'.$i.'" onClick="checkTotal()"/></td>';  
  <td ALIGN="right" ><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay now" onClick="validateForm()"></td>

?>
```

My js script:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["payform"]["pay[]"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="0"){
        alert("Can not be empty or 0!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**if it's blank or 0 then make user return to the form to fill the correct one,
How can I do that ??**

Comment: Do you have a typo? `document.forms["payform"]["p[]"].value` should be `document.forms["payform"]["pay[]"].value`?

Comment: I suggest using `if (x.length <= 0 || parseInt(x) == 0)`. Try it._

Answer (score 0):

To check blank you can write

```
if (x=="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an expression to return `true` if `x` is either `0` or blank, did I get it right?

The just do `if(!x)` - both the number `0` and an empty string evaluate to 0 in js.

Comment: yup and if it's blank, return to the form, how can i do that ?

Comment: if (x==null || x=="0" || x="") ....doesn't work, I put on onSubmit form...onSubmit="return Amount()">